# How to add subscript (the html <sub> tag) programmatically?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to add subscript programmatically using javascript. I'm using the `.sub();` command in javascript.

My expected outcome:

```html
<p>a = b + r<sub>1</sub></p>
```

My code:

```js
function addSubscript(){
  var text = 'a = b + r' + '1'.sub();
  var para = document.createElement("p");
  var text_p1 = document.createTextNode(text);
  para.appendChild(text_p1);
  
  document.getElementById("print").appendChild(para);
}
```

```css
button{
   width: 20%;
   margin-left: 40%;
}
#print{
   width: 100%;
   text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="addSubscript()">Add subscript</button>
<div id="print"></div>
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Did you mean `.sub()` instead of `.sup()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Content inside text nodes render as-is, without formatting. To apply a subscript use `innerHTML`:

```js
function addSubscript(){
  var text = 'a = b + r' + '1'.sub();
  var para = document.createElement("p");
  para.innerHTML = text;
  
  document.getElementById("print").appendChild(para);
}
```

```css
button {
  font-size: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 26px;
}
#print {
  font-size: 16px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="addSubscript()">Add subscript</button>
<div id="print"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simple write HTML content in the innerHTML & while rendering, it will render with HTML properties. 
For example here, you can use - **< sub >** tag itself

```js
function addSubscript(){
  var text = 'a = b + r' + '<sub>'+'1'+'</sub>';
  var para = document.createElement("p");
  para.innerHTML = text;
  
  document.getElementById("print").appendChild(para);
}
```

```css
button {
  font-size: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 26px;
}
#print {
  font-size: 16px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="addSubscript()">Add subscript</button>
<div id="print"></div>
```